# Sharing pipe handle across a multi-threaded pipe client

Tags: multithreading, client, pipe, sharing

I've been trying to determine if I can share a pipe handle (on windows) across threads of a pipe client.  My initial thinking was that I couldn't because unless I synchronized the threads the data could show up interleaved at the server and thus cause problems.  However I'm now wondering whether a pipe of PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE and PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE will allow me to have a multi-threaded pipe client share a single pipe handle.  Does anyone have a definitive answer on this?

The reason I'm looking to share a single pipe handle across client threads is to save the cost of opening the pipe each time I want to send data.  I can't easily cache the pipe handles for the client threads because I'm not creating the client threads.

I've included a snippet from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365605(v=vs.85).aspx which describes the pipe type mode.  I've highlighted the part which makes me wonder whether message mode will accomplish what I'm trying to do.

> ...
>
> Type Mode
>
> The type mode of a pipe determines how data is written to a named
>   pipe. Data can be transmitted through a named pipe as either a stream
>   of bytes or as a stream of messages. The pipe server specifies the
>   pipe type when calling CreateNamedPipe to create an instance of a
>   named pipe. The type modes must be the same for all instances of a
>   pipe.
>
> To create a byte-type pipe, specify PIPE_TYPE_BYTE or use the default
>   value. The data is written to the pipe as a stream of bytes, and the
>   system does not differentiate between the bytes written in different
>   write operations.
>
> To create a message-type pipe, specify PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE. **The system
>   treats the bytes written in each write operation to the pipe as a
>   message unit**. The system always performs write operations on
>   message-type pipes as if write-through mode were enabled.
>
> ...

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 3):

Both ReadFile and WriteFile WinAPI functions are **thread-safe**. Unlike I wrote before (sorry about that), this thread safety doesn't guarantee that concurrent writes from the different threads won't be interleaved. In other words, it is not guaranteed that the thread that starts writing its data first will complete before some other thread gains write access. From MSDN:

> Although a single-sector write is atomic, a multi-sector write is not guaranteed to be atomic unless you are using a transaction (that is, the handle created is a transacted handle; for example, a handle created using CreateFileTransacted).

This would indicate that it is possible to have atomic write using transacted operations, but I don't know much about transactions in this context.

*To redeem myself*, I'll try to propose an alternate solution to your problem. You could have a separate **writer** thread in your client that has exclusive write rights for the pipe. All other threads push their messages to a FIFO queue while writer thread reads the queue and sends the data through the pipe. This is better approach than locking the entire write operation, as enqueue/dequeue operations are much faster and threads won't be blocked for long.

You could implement the queue in a way that writer thread can wait on it, and wake up only when there are messages in the queue. Otherwise, writer thread will have a busy loop and this is a nasty solution.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying since WriteFile(), which is what my client will be using, is thread safe the data won't be interleaved.  It would seem then that the OS is synchronizing the calls.  Is that correct?  So if two threads are using the same FILE handle, to chose a similar but slightly different example, and they each write some buffer of bytes to the file, those bytes will not be interleaved regardless of whether the client buffer is bigger than the OS or runtime library buffer and thus have to be chunked up themselves into multiple writes?

Comment: I apologise for my thoughtless answer :(. After reading your comment I realise that what I wrong was very wrong and I updated my answer. Please re-check my answer.

Comment: This comes back to my original question.  I assumed that a byte oriented pipe could have the potential of interleaved 'buffers'.  The message oriented pipe gave me the impression that *maybe* the OS is doing something special to ensure each write buffer is intact within the pipe and thus would handle the scenario I have outlined where multiple client threads are sharing the same pipe handle.

Comment: By the way, I updated my question with a snippet from the pipe type documentation.

Comment: I don't think setting the pipe type to PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE will solve the problem. If BYTE mode is set then OS doesn't distinguish between data written in different write operations. So, you can end up reading bytes from several write operations on the reading end. If mode is set to MESSAGE, than data written using write is like a transmission packet. Read operation then reads one packet at the time. BUT. This doesn't mean that OS will lock write operation to prevent data interleaving as we discussed. Writing to single-sector is atomic, multiple-sector writes doesn't have to be.